# Javascript domain protect script

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have made a `.js` file and I would like to protect it a little.  Just from small leechers, obviously more advanced people will be able to figure it out.

I'd like to add to my script, something to check which domain the file is being run on. If it's not my two domains (`example1.com`, `example2.com`), it will redirect to my domain. Sort of like an iframe buster.

Then I can take the whole code and obfuscate it a little. My purpose is to prevent someone from downloading the .js and using it on their server.

My code:

```
if(typeof(width)=='undefined')width=655;
if(typeof(height)=='undefined')height=540;
if(width<655)width=655;if(height<540)height=540;
if(width<height)height=width;
document.write('<ifr'+'ame src="/streams/hd/'+ ch+'.php" scrolling=no frameborder=0 width='+ width+' height='+ height+' scrolling=no allowtransparency=true id=thatframe ></ifr'+'ame>');
```

Is there something I can add to this that will only allow the script to be run on my websites? `example1.com`, `example2.com`?

Comment: The best way to protect your JS files is to use a JavaScript minifier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.location.host` that returns the host name, then check in your script like

```
var _host = document.location.host;
if( _host == "example1.com" || _host == "example2.com" ){
    // do things for example1.com
}
```

If you want to protect your JS file then use [jscompress](http://jscompress.com/) the compressed version.

Comment: That certainly helps me Jogesh. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic solution, I know there are better ways to get the current URL.

```
if (document.URL.indexOf('http://example.com') == 0) {
   // Then you're on example.com.
}
```

Note that this works for subfolders also, e.g. http://example.com/foo/bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use document.domain like this ([MDN Reference for document.domain)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.domain)

```
var allowedDomains = ['example1.com', 'example2.com'];

if (allowedDomains.indexOf(document.domain) == -1) {
  // Code to redirect here
}
```